# Sending an email from Gmail Alias in a Google Workspace

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am struggling with sending an email from an alias account I have in a Google Workspace. This is so I can send emails from within my website using a generic email address (such as info@, or support@). This means the domain will remain the same, but the text before the @ will be different.

I have created the alias, and from my reading, I can send emails from an alias but I need to use my real account to authenticate. I have also created the App Password and emails send, just not from the alias.

The code I am using is

```
var client = new SmtpClient(_host, 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myRealUsername@domain.com", GetPassword()),
    EnableSsl = true
};
          
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("myAlias@domain.com", "Support"); 
message.To.Add("anotherAccount@domain.com");
message.Subject = "test";
client.Send(message);
```

The problem I have is when the code executes, the email is always sent from `myRealUsername@domain.com`

What do I need to do to ensure the email is sent from `myAlias@domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was fine

Despite having set up the alias in admin.google.com, I had to log into Gmail, click the cog, then more settings.

From here, click the accounts tab, and under the Send mail as, click on `Add another email address`, creating another alias. Not sure why I have options to do this in 2 places

Comment: I am having the same issue, we need to add the same alias email as 'Add another email address?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that